# Can RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt() return incorrect data?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Can `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt()` output incorrect data? 
Or will it always throw Exception with message "The parameter is incorrect" or any other Exception, whether it's unable to decrypt in a proper way?

Situation is:

1. I generate RSA pair using `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(true)`
2. I send modulus and exponent to the other side
3. I receive encrypted data
4. I successfully decrypt data with the same RSA parameters without any errors, but get data in length of 30 bytes
5. The other side does state, that plain data was of 32 bytes length

Is this even possible? What am I missing here?

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
var rsaParams = provider.ExportParameters(true);
rsaParams.Exponent = new byte[] { 0x65 };

byte[] publicKey = rsaParams.Modulus;

// Send public key to the other side with exponent 0x65, 
// Decrypt received data

byte[] decryptedData = provider.Decrypt(encryptedData, false);
```

Comment: What is the padding used? OAEP? Anyway, [32-byte still too small](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/18298). Could you post the encryption codes, too?

Comment: @kelalaka: It uses PKCS #1, ver 1.5, block type 2 padding (i.e. padding with mostly random bytes).

Comment: It is *possible* but unlikely to have `Decrypt` appear to succeed when the private key or the data is wrong. After decrypting with PKCS#1 version 1.5 type 2 padding, the decryptor should check the structure of the decrypted data that the high order two bytes are 00 02, and that there is at least 8 random bytes that are not equal 0, then a byte that equals 0, followed by more bytes. It's possible that even more checks are done, but I'm not an expert on the .NET implementation. Thus on average you'd expect about 1 in 65536 bad decrypts to pass through without notice.

Comment: The ciphertext was encoded with base64 or similar before transmit?

Comment: Your cannot sensibly change your public exponent after the private exponent has been created.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk So, the default is PKCS#1 version 1.5 type 2 padding.

Comment: @kelalaka: The second argument to Decrypt or Encrypt sets the padding. true means OAEP, false means PKCS #1 ver 1.5

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just replace the public exponent like you do *after* key generation (which happens in the constructor). By default a public exponent is likely set to 65537 (fifth prime of Fermat, F4) and you just set it to `0x65`. If the public and private key do not match then the calculations will fail.

Comment: That wouldn't explain the results he claims to be observing. I suspect the code he's posted is not the same code that produced the results he's claiming.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Yeah, true, it would only work if the padding is not set - if that's even possible for .NET. Maybe a provider or something that forgets to check the return statement, I don't know. I guess we have to close the question, currently we see water burning.